# HTML5 canvas drawImage and scale performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-canvas

I hear that `ctx.drawImage` with destination width/height difference from source width/height will lead to an additional scale operation, it isn't performance friendly operation. But how about this:

```
ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);

for(var i in img) {
    ctx.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0);
}
```

Is it difference (in performance point of view) with:

```
for(var i in img) {
    ctx.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, img[i].width, img[i].height, 0, 0, img[i].width * 0.5, img[i].height * 0.5);
}
```

Comment: I guess this depends on the web browser and the implementation (HW accelerated/SW renderer/size of the image). The best way is to write a simple performance test using a service like jsperf.com and then ask friends to run it on different browsers.

Comment: A great tool for measuring things like this is https://jsperf.com. Unfortunately it's down at the moment.